# Solr schema to store comma separated values into a single field & fetch using PHP

Tags: solr

I'm using SolR search in my application. I have set of Books (permission based) for accessing to different users based on the roles assigned to them during registration. Now when user comes in searches for a particular book, if the book configured for his role (passing role_id dynamically in the query) then only it has to display in the search result, else shouldn't list.

While indexing in solr I'm using GROUP_CONCAT(roles,' ') {space separated values} function which maps to roles field in the solr document.

I have the schema designed as shown here `<field name="roleid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />`.
While searching for the record I'm passing as 'roleid:11' for which no result found is returning.

Example during indexing "roleid : '2 7 11 10'".
While querying the data I'm passing "roleid:7", but no data returned from the query. Please do suggest on scema definition for this type and also select query change (if any, like IN clause or some thing similar).

Thanks in advance..
Vasu.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below `fieldType` for your field `roleid`

```
<fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**WhitespaceTokenizerFactory** : Simple tokenizer that splits the text stream on whitespace and returns sequences of non-whitespace characters as tokens.

```
<field name="roleid" type="text_ws" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

and in the query you can search on `q=books:Apple&fq=(roleid:1 OR roleid:7)`

**Note** : Once you update the `schema.xml`, please restart the server and re-index the data.

Comment: Hi Abhijith, Thanks for the reply,

Answer (score 0):

While posting the values inside the query we must post as $roles = array(0=>2, 1=>7, 2=>11,3=>10 ); to the Solr query to solve my problem... Thanks to all